# Remove brackets from string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string with brackets which I want to remove.
I tried:

```
L0 <- c("(ABC)","DEF","GHI","J(K)")

L1  <- gsub( '()',"",L0)
L1  <- gsub( '(',"",L0)
L1  <- gsub( '(',"",L0)

L1
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a single `gsub` to remove the bracket.  Place it in square bracket to evaluate it literally.

```
gsub("[()]", "", L0)
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JK"
```

There is also an option `fixed = TRUE`.  In that case

```
gsub("(", "", L0, fixed = TRUE) # remove the `(`
gsub(")", "", L0, fixed = TRUE) # remove the `)`
```

and for both

```
gsub("(", "", gsub(")", "", L0, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JK"
```

---

The issue is that when we use `()`, it implies a meaning i.e. to capture some groups.  For example in the following code, we remove substring and capture the second character

```
sub("^.(.).*", "\\1", L0)
#[1] "A" "E" "H" "("
```